# How do I stop pulse ducking (reducing) totem audio volume?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, totem, mumble

I listen to podcasts in the background, but also use tools like mumble for staying in touch with my gaming group (steamlug). After recently updating to 14.04 from 12.04 this behaviour started:

Whenever someone talks on mumble, totem and Minecraft volumes adjust to 51%. I haven’t loaded the ducking module, and it doesn’t appear to be in the list either. I know there are roles in pulse to control this, but I cannot find which module is doing this.

When I spotted module-intended-roles in the `pactl list` I unloaded it, but it doesn’t seem to have made a difference.
Thought maybe module-filter-apply was doing it, unloaded that too, no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a little source diving in Mumble when I had an volume attenuation problem as well. Your problem resides with Mumble, not with PulseAudio. Mumble has a setting in Configure->Settings->(click the Advanced checkbox)->Audio Output. There's a slider that says "Attenuate applications by..." with two checkboxes underneath. Uncheck them both in order to disable the attentuation.

Mumble uses the PulseAudio API to manually adjust the volume levels of all applications except itself to do the attenuation. I found this particularly annoying since Mumble attenuates *all* applications regardless of where they're actually outputting to. For example, if I was watching a movie over HDMI (different output) and using Mumble for some reason, any time somebody talked the movie volume would go down. There was no way around this but to write a patch ;). I have a [pull request](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble/pull/1198) at the Mumble Git that avoids attenuation if the audio output is not the same output that Mumble is using.

Comment: thanks! ‐ had a friend suggest that mumble was doing this and had forgotten to answer my own question - but you answered it well